# Android Uploading image to web hosting server

Tags: php, android, image, file-upload

I wish to develop an android application which able to send image browsing from image gallery and upload it to the free web hosting server.

From past week, I successfully registered a free web hosting as below :
www.000webhost.com

I followed the steps shown to upload images From Android To Server Using Multipart Post Entity as below: 
http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/08/upload-files-from-android-to-server.html

The code executed smoothly from eclipse.
When i pressed the upload button, it works fine from Android device apps

The thing is the uploaded image doesn't appear in the remote server's "uploads" folder.

Any solution for this problems ?? 
Is that we allow to upload an image to web hosting server?

Thanks ...

Comment: is the folder writeable in my server I need to give it permission to read and write(using filezilla set the access to 777 or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. First convert image to byte array, then send that byte array to server and on server side, create image using that byte array. There should be any mechanism on server side to create image from byte array and then test. I think using this your problem will be resolved.